# Has a B-side unexpectedly become more popular than A-side?

Tags: history, vinyl, record

When released for the first time, a single usually suppose to have a hit on the A-side, and a secondary song not supposed to be a hit, on the B-side. That song was basically used to fill the B-side, and producers didn't give hight hopes on it.

The scope of my question doesn't include singles that knowingly  featured two hits (sometimes called *double A-side*) like The Beatles' [*We Can Work It Out / Day Tripper*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Beatles-We-Can-Work-It-Out-Day-Tripper/release/4473502) or where the letter A or B doesn't appear on the label.

I'm focussing in singles where the B-side became a massive hit, and A-side almost forgotten.

**Has a B-side unexpectedly overtake a A-side, in terms of success, popularity?**

Comment: "We Will Rock You" was the B side of "We are the Champions", but that's really more of a double-A type situation.  I'm certain I've head of other cases that are a better fit for your query, but I'm having trouble bringing them to mind.

Comment: Do you want answers to be where the record company actually changed the A/B designation & started promoting the other side... or records that were bought because of the B-side, or received airplay on the B-side, without ever being officially 'turned over'.

Comment: @Tetsujin, either could be good. My scope is when the B-side was neglected, by the disc company and/or the artists, in front of the A-side. Then the A-side is a failer compared to the success of the B-side.

Answer (score 11):

After a little research (A sides in parentheses):

- “Rock Around the Clock” (“Thirteen Women (And Only One Man in
  Town)”)– Bill Haley and His Comets in 1954.
- “Tequila” (“Train to Nowhere") – The Champs
- "Unchained Melody” ( “Hung on You.”) – The Righteous Brothers 1965.
- "Ruby Tuesday”* (“Let’s Spend the Night Together”) – The Rolling
  Stones
- “I Will Survive” (“Substitute”) - Gloria Gaynor
- “Push It” (“Tramp”) - Salt-N-Pepa
- "Dear God" ("Grass") - XTC

This only includes songs where the B side was substantially more popular than the A.  I'm sure there are others, but these are some big ones.

* = became a hit after being re-released

Comment: If EPs are allowed (not clear), I would mention "[Tous les garçons et les filles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tous_les_gar%C3%A7ons_et_les_filles)" by Francoise Hardy (1962), with the much less successful "Oh oh chéri" on the A-side.

Comment: I'm not sure you can say that The sweetest thing is more of a hit than Where the streets have no name, which is still played at every U2 concert

Comment: Colloquially, The Sweetest Thing hit #6 in Australia on its rerelease in 1998, and I've heard it a million times on the radio for that reason, but barely know  of Where the Streets Have No Name.

Comment: @GuillaumeFache I just looked it up, and "Streets" was a substantially bigger hit (except in Canada), "Sweetest Thing" was just more recent.  So, off the list it goes...

Answer (score 4):

Green Day's Good Riddance (Time Of Your Life) initially appeared as a B-side on their Brain Stew / Jaded single from their album Insomniac.

It eventually was re-released as the second single on Nimrod and became a massive hit.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I've been checking for [*Brain Stew / Jaded*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Green-Day-Brain-Stew-Jaded/master/68777) single on Discogs, but I can't find any issue that features *Time of your Life*. Do you have a link to confirm it has been a B-Side?

Comment: The song is actually called "Good Riddance".

Comment: Could you confirm @JanJohannsen is right and edit your question?

Answer (score 4):

I've turned up a few more .. with notes as to which were officially turned over or re-released

- I Am the Walrus (Hello Goodbye) - Beatles 1967
  Never turned over
- Green Onions (Behave Yourself) - Booker T & The MGs 1962
  Re-released 1962.
- Half The World Away (Whatever) - Oasis 1994
  [afaik] Never turned over
- Suffragette City (Starman) - David Bowie 1972
  Released to promote ChangesOneBowie in 1976, was never a hit in its own right]
- How Soon Is Now (William, It Was Really Nothing) - Smiths 1984
  Re-released 1985
- God Only Knows (Wouln't It Be Nice) - Beach Boys 1966
  Released as the A-side in some countries, but as a B-side only, in the US.
- Maggie May (Reason To Believe) - Rod Stewart 1971
  Never turned over
- Into the Groove (Angel) - Madonna 1985
  Released as an A-side worldwide, but not in the US
- Always on my Mind (Separate Ways) - Elvis Presley
  US possibly later changed to double-A [wikipedia unclear], UK A-side
- The Model (Computer Love) - Kraftwerk 1978
  Re-issued 1981 with A&B reversed.
- Rock'n'Roll Part 2 (Rock'n'Roll Part 1) - Gary Glitter 1972
  Unclear as to whether it was ever turned over - probably not.
- You Can't Always Get What You Want (Honky Tonk Women) - Rolling Stones 1969
  Re-released 1973

Records purportedly bought for the B-Side, yet could not be played on the radio

- There Ain't Half Been Some Clever Bastards (Hit Me With Your Rhythm Stick) Ian Dury & the Blockheads 1978
- Magic Roundabout (Funky Moped) Jasper Carrott 1975

Near misses...

- Mustang Sally (Good Lovin) - The Young Rascals
  Never a hit for them, the Wilson Pickett cover beat them to it.

Comment: "Hello Goodbye" reached #1 on the charts; "I Am the Walrus" did not. I also feel like I've heard "Starman" a lot more than "Suffragette City," but that's anecdotal. Certainly neither of those A-sides are "almost forgotten" per the original question! How are you judging popularity here?

Comment: I am the Walrus could never chart, as I said; they never turned it over. It's the one that's still played to this day, though - plus it has a video, so it is used on TV too. Suffragette City hasn't been off the playlists since last year. Interesting you missed the most striking one - Maggie May was also never turned over.. however it was performed on Top of the Pops, which almost never played anything that wasn't an actual of the moment hit.

Comment: When you say "turned over", do you mean re-released as an A-side? Since the charts are largely (even primarily?) based on airplay, why would it be necessary for a song to be released as an A-side to chart?

Comment: Whose charts are based on airplay? Though that might have been charged in recent years [since the demise of the 45 rpm single as the mainstay of the charts] in the UK it was always based entirely on sales, airplay was no factor. ...and yes 'turned over'  ==  specifically re-released as a A, with the original A as the B-side.

Comment: I just wiki'd charts and read a little bit about them. It sounds like the *Billboard* charts (an Americanism, admittedly) are primarily based on airplay, though I could be misunderstanding the article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_chart

Answer (score 4):

Ritchie Valens' "[La Bamba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Bamba_(song))" was the B-side of "[Donna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donna_(Ritchie_Valens_song))". While Donna reached #2 and "La Bamba" only #22 on Billboard Hot 100, I think "La Bamba" could be considered "more popular" in the long term. Valens was credited with a #1 hit when the Los Lobos version reached #1.  Also "La Bamba" ranked No. 98 in VH1's 100 Greatest Songs of Rock and Roll in 1999.

However, I don't think "Donna" was "almost forgotten".

Answer (score 4):

*Ice Ice Baby* was initially released as the B-side to **Vanilla Ice**'s cover of [*Play That Funky Music*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Vanilla-Ice-Play-That-Funky-Music-Ice-Ice-Baby/release/2014654).
<sub>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Ice_Baby) from Wikipedia.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Its actually kind of tough to tell for sure, at least from sales figures, since a B side was (obviously) sold as an inseparable package with its A side. Probably the best way to tell would be from the imperfect measure of radio airplay time.

My personal favorite instance of a B side getting more airplay is Led Zepplin's [Hey, Hey, What Can I Do?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hey,_Hey,_What_Can_I_Do). It was a B-side for the released single of [The Immigrant Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immigrant_Song). That song got no little airplay itself, but there was definitely a period in the early 80's when I was hearing *Hey, Hey* on the radio way more. Also, since Immigrant Song was originally on Led Zeppelin II, its a fair bet that rather a lot of the sales of the single to your typical hardcore Zeppelin fan were to acquire the B side, not the A side.

But even more interestingly, Public Enemy wrote a (freaking great) song *about* B-sides doing better than A-sides: [B Side Wins Again](http://www.publicenemy.com/album/3/71/b-side-wins-again.html).

> You roll in your ride, the DJ decides to play it on the radio; the A
>   side. He gives it a try, but never gives it a try and the people
>   request the best on the B side.

That song itself [sampled several B-sides](http://www.whosampled.com/Public-Enemy/B-Side-Wins-Again/).

Answer (score 3):

Already mentioned in another answer, but I wanted to add a little more detail: *Dear God* by **XTC** was originally a B-side-only release on the single [*Grass*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/XTC-Grass/master/70150), and became so popular so quickly that it supplanted an original album track, *Mermaid Smiled*, on the US release of the album *Skylarking*:

- The original release of the album [*Skylarking*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/XTC-Skylarking/master/71079) has *Mermaid Smiled* in track 12.
- The [US release of *Skylarking*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/XTC-Skylarking/release/2569804) in 1986 has *Dear God* in track 12.
  <sub>Other source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylarking).</sub>

Then [*Dear God*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/XTC-Dear-God/master/70104) was released as A-side.

Answer (score 2):

Some additional ones to supplement [@Briller](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/4798/431) and [@ChrisSunami](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/4799/431)'s answers:

- "[Wipe Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wipe_Out_(instrumental))" by the Surfaris, original A-Side was "Surfer Joe"
- "[Maggie May](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggie_May)" by Rod Stewart, original A-Side was "Reason To Believe"
- "[Rock and Roll Part 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_and_Roll_(Gary_Glitter_song))" by Gary Glitter, original A-Side was "Rock and Roll Part 1"
- "[Fingertips - Part 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingertips)" by Little Stevie Wonder, original A-Side was "Fingertips - Part 1"

More [surprise](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/music/features/the-surprise-b-side-the-flipside-was-often-top-of-the-pops-6282711.html) hit [B-Sides](http://plusheartstar.com/2013/08/hit-songs-that-were-b-sides/) can be [found](http://www.smoothradio.com/best-music/most-amazing-songs-released-as-b-sides/) in these [links](http://www.classicpopicons.com/top-10-b-side-hits/).

Answer (score 0):

Pearl Jam's "[Yellow Ledbetter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hs8y3kneqrs)" was the B-side to Jeremy, and it went on to be one of the band's biggest songs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was about B-sides that became popular, and you're right, Yellow Ledbetter was popular, but it was also about A-sides that were not as popular as expected. Jeremy is a very popular song.

Comment: That's true, but I'd still say Yellow Ledbetter is a lot more well known tham Jeremy to non-PJ fans

Comment: Not so sure of that. I'm not a Pearl Jam fan, but I sure do know Jeremy, I could probably sing it by heart. It was all over the radio for ages. I just checked out the video to Yellow Ledbetter, I don't think I've ever heard it before. According to wikipedia, it didn't crack the Billboard Hot 100, and only reached a max of 21st spot on the rock charts. Jeremy reached #5 on both Mainstream and Modern rock charts, and #79 in the Hot 100. (Why do I suddenly feel like I'm in "High Fidelity"?)